# Image rotation while uploading from phones

Tags: php, android, ios

I need some help with the image rotation while uploading from my android phone (can't test with iPhones because I don't have one) so, I will post my code bellow, but it is not working at least when I upload it the image is not in the correct rotation it appears sideways.

This is my php code:

```
$imgID = $_POST['postID'];
$newname = "$imgID.jpg";

$filename = $_FILES['fileField']['name'];
$filePath = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath); // provided that the image is jpeg. Use relevant function otherwise
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
        break;
        case 6:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
        break;
        case 8:
        $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
        break;
        default:
        $image = $imageResource;
    } 
}

move_uploaded_file(imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90),"../pic/$newname");
```

My HTML Form and Javascript to update one div with the image:

```
<script>
     function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(200)
                        .height(200);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>
<form action='' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='postID' value='<?php echo $row['postID'];?>'>
    <p><label>Imagem</label><br /><input type="file" name="fileField" onchange="readURL(this);" /></p>
    <img id="blah" src="../pic/<?php echo $row['postID']; ?>.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="your image" />
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'></p>
</form>
```